# Object doesn't support property or method 'getContext' in below IE 9 versions

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I am using canvas element to draw curve along with text. It is working fine in chrome, Firefox, IE 9. But in IE 8,7 this is not working. Showing the error like:

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'getContext'

---

I searched in Google then i found `Excanvas.js` will figure out this problem, but I am getting the same error.

Thank you.

`<head><!--[if IE]><script src="js/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]--></head>`

My html canvas code:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="679" height="290"></canvas>
```

My js code:

```
function drawTextAlongArc(context, str, centerX, centerY, radius, angle) {
    var len = str.length, s;

    context.save();            
    context.translate(centerX, centerY);            
    context.rotate(-1 * angle / 2);            
    context.rotate(-1 * (angle / len) / 2);            

    for(var n = 0; n < len; n++) {              
       context.rotate(angle / len);        
       context.save();
       context.translate(0, -1 * radius);

       s = str[n];              
       context.fillText(s, 0, 0);        
       context.restore();
    }    
    context.restore();
}

var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),             
    context = canvas.getContext('2d'),            
    centerX = canvas.width / 2,            
    centerY = canvas.height + 40,            
    angle = Math.PI * 0.8,            
    radius = 250;          

context.font = 'bold 30pt Ubuntu'; 
context.textAlign = 'center';
context.fillStyle = 'orange';
context.strokeStyle = '#336699';
context.lineWidth = 10;

drawTextAlongArc(context, 'Sustainable Skill Solutions', centerX, centerY, radius, angle);


// draw circle underneath text
context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius +70, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
context.stroke();
```

Comment: Because canvas is [only supported in IE>=9](http://caniuse.com/#feat=canvas).

Comment: Can you show your code on using `excanvas.js`?

Comment: My html canvas code:<canvas id="myCanvas" width="679" height="290">
       </canvas>

Comment: Have you done what the [instruction](https://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/wiki/Instructions) told and include `excanvas.js` before document loads?

Comment: @Passerby:yeah i included excanvas.js in head section

Answer (score 5):

You need to run your JS only when document is ready.

This may not be necessary for browsers supporting `<canvas>`, but for IE<9, `excanvas.js` works **after** document loaded, so you'll need to run your JS after that.

Change your JS to:

```js
function drawTextAlongArc()
{
    /* ... */
}
function onLoad()
{
    var canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas"),
        context=canvas.getContext("2d");
    /* ... */
}
if(window.addEventListener)
{
    window.addEventListener("load",onLoad,false);
}
else if(window.attachEvent)
{
    window.attachEvent("onload",onLoad);
}
```